# How to add new key with value in registry via java?

Tags: java, registry

I'm running tests on IE11. To do it I made some changes in registry. I have created new key 'FEATURE_BFCACHE' in folder 'FeatureControl'. Then I have added new 'DWord' value to 'FEATURE_BFCACHE' named 'iexplore.exe' with value '0'. I have done it manually. But now try to do it from my program. I wrote this but it does not work.

```
String[] c = new String[]{"reg", "add", "\"HKLM\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BFCACHE\"",
                "/v", "\"iexplore.exe\"", "/t", "REG_DWORD", d", "0", "/f"};
try {
    new ProcessBuilder(c).start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After some changes I have line that properly works in command line `reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE1" /t REG_DWORD /v iexplore.exe /d 0 /f` but does not work from java code

```
System.out.println("Creating new folder");
String[] c = new String[]{"reg", "add", "\"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BFCACHE1\"",
   "/t", "REG_DWORD", "/v", "iexplore.exe", "/d", "0", "/f"};
try {
    new ProcessBuilder(c).start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Maybe to execute this command I need run as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting strings is only needed when you run a command in a cmd promt or pass it as a single String, when you use a String array with a ProcessBuilder the quote characters will be passed to the called program as literal quote characters.

Try:

```
String[] c = new String[]{"reg", "add", "HKLM\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BFCACHE",
            "/v", "iexplore.exe", "/t", "REG_DWORD", "/d", "0", "/f"};
```

Comment: Your command also seems to be missing the `/` on `/d`. Other then that, try to print stdout/stderr of the executed command (e.g. by using [`inheritIO()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--) on the process builder), maybe there's a clue. Maybe your program isn't running with enough rights to make this change?

Comment: this line works in command line `reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE1" /t REG_DWORD /v iexplore.exe /d 0 /f`
but when I put it into java code does not works

Answer (score 0):

to modify registry we need execute command line as administrator, so if i open IntelliJ Idea as administrator it works